# Add row in google Spreadsheet with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Adds the value below the line created earlier. I'm trying to get me to add a line at **"2:2"** and put the value on that line, and the other values ​​stay below. The maximum result I got so far was to make the new line erase the old one and paste the new value in the same field.

```
var Sheet1 = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  
  var LastRow = Sheet1.getLastRow();

  
  Sheet1.getRange(LastRow+1, 1).setValue(name);
```

Any solutions to add a line and paste the values ​​in **2:2** and the old values ​​underneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `insertRowAfter()`

#### Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet1 = SpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  // insert row at row 2, moving all rows below the first row down a single row
  Sheet1.insertRowAfter(1);
  var name = [['1.5']];
  // then write data at row 2
  Sheet1.getRange(2, 1, name.length, name[0].length).setValues(name);
}
```

#### Sample data:

[image]

#### Output:

[image]